# protoc-gen-gprc_python: program not found or is not executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, grpc, grpc-python

When I try to generate proto files using Python's `grpc_tools.protoc` library:

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I protos --python_out=. --gprc_python_out=. protos/test.proto
```

it fails with the error

```
protoc-gen-gprc_python: program not found or is not executable
--gprc_python_out: protoc-gen-gprc_python: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

I've already installed the following packages in my conda environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge grpclib
conda install grpcio grpcio-tools
```

```
$ python -m grpc_tools.protoc --version
libprotoc 3.6.1
```

What is my conda environment missing that is prevent me from running my above command? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo.

You want `--grpc_python_out=.`

You have `--gprc_python_out=.`

Comment: Thanks, I want `--python_grpc_out=.` Possible typo in your answer